# Multiple windows, Windows Universal

Tags: windows-runtime, visual-studio-2015, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I would like to have a second, (and more) windows for my windows universal app to run on a PC. But to my surprise this does not seem easy. In WPF for example I could add a new item to my project and select a window. In Universal, there is no "Window" in new items. I can declare an object of class windows.ui.xaml.window but I cannot instantiate it (there is no new) or show it. How do I launch another window? Thanks

Comment: This is a native feature of Template 10 for UWP: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Services/NavigationService/NavigationService.cs#L133

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [sample available on Microsoft's UWP GitHub repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews) which covers creating multiple views for your application. I can provide more information or help if you need it

Comment: Ok, that does make new windows - but it is horribly complicated!! In WPF for example I could just make a new window and put some controls on it with the designer, and just do something like dim w as new MyWindow, w.show - is there any equivalent to this in universal?

Comment: @Ianb-it can't be the same as WPF and still be portable across the various Windows platforms (like Phone, Xbox) and when Windows Desktop is running in tablet mode. The management of secondary Windows is unfortunately more complex to handle these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding something which is quite simple, takes a page by type, creates it and a window with it inside, and returns the page object created:

```
    async Task<Page> CreatePageWindowAsync(Type p)
    {
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        Page pg = null;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(p, null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            pg = frame.Content as Page;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
        return (pg);
    }
```